# Instantiate an object and protect its properties externally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a class that instantiates another class, like this

```
public abstract class ResponseAdapter
{
    PingResult result = new PingResult();

    public PingResult Result 
    {
       get { return result; } 
    }
}
```

Although I want Result to be public, I don't want its content changeable outside of the protected environment.

I know I could create a constructor for Result and make things read only, but the class that instantiates PingResult sets its properties individually. Are there any keywords or techniques that will allow me to maintain PingResult's properties readonly outside of the current class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in C# which gives the feature you're asking about.

There are two options you could consider.

1. Make the `PingResult` immutable and expose it. Disadvantage is that no one can modify it.
2. Expose the `PingResult` with some abstraction which is immutable. I.e `IPingResult` interface which doesn't provides members to mutate the state. Still you can keep the `PingResult` mutable which can be used to modify it in the current class in the question.

With second approach you can choose to mark the `PingResult` class private which makes it unaccessible outside the class and expose the instance as `IPingResult`. This way, you can be sure that only `ResponseAdapter` can modify the `PingResult` because other classes don't even see the setters; They only get to see the readonly interface.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps create a wrapper/proxy class for `PingResult` (e.g. `PingResultWrapper`) which `ResponseAdapter` exposes with its property. Any edits made on `PingResultWrapper` will be mediated through that, so you have total control on what changes can be made to the wrapped `PingResult` object. Also, better to have `PingResult` and `WrappedPingResult` implement the same interface, so that the caller can treat it more abstractly (i.e. doesn't need to know about the implementation details).

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface that contains only getters(`IPingResult`) and inherit PingResult from it.

```
 public PingResult Result 
    {
       get { return result; } 
    }
```

will be changed to return the interface instead of the class:

```
public IPingResult Result 
        {
           get { return result; } 
        }
```